# new $className(); php version support

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

As far as I know, class instantiation using a variable `new $className();` is supported in 5.3 for sure, however I'm not sure about 5.2 version and I can't check if this works OK on 5.2.

Can anyone tell what versions are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt specific to PHP5. It will work in PHP4 as well.

See http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php#99638

Comment: Thanks :) The link really clarify all :)

Answer (score 1):

tested in 5.2.4-2, and runs fine :)

edit ---

In PHP 5.2 you can't do `$className::method()`, you get the famous

```
unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

but you can do `new $className();`

Comment: You can use call_user_func(array('class', 'method'), ...) instead for static functions.

Comment: You also can't access properties like that in PHP < 5.3: `$className::$prop`

Answer (score 0):

The manual says introduced in 5.3.0

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: It's for `new static` I think

Comment: Are you referring to the example #5 ? That one it's for instantiation using another object